# Apollo InMemoryCache cannot find keyfields

Tags: reactjs, apollo-client

I'm trying to [configure caching](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/caching/cache-configuration/) and I'm getting this error:

> Missing field 'Customer_ID' while computing key fields

I'm new to version two so I'm upgrading from version one (no caching) to v3. My understanding is that in the `typePolicies`, you have the `type` then its fields.

```js
// Code not shown for simplicity
[..]

const options = {
  typePolicies: {
    Customer: { // type
      keyFields: ['Customer_ID'] // field
    }
  }
}

const cache = new InMemoryCache(options)
[..]
```

And here's the type declaration:

```js
type Customer {
  Customer_ID: Int
  [..]
}
```

Finally, my query, with fragments not shown but you do get the understanding:

```js
const CustomerDetailsFragment = gql`
  fragment CustomerDetailsFragment on Customer {
    Customer_ID
    [..]
  }
`;

query GetActiveCustomer {
  activeCustomer {
    ...CustomerDetailsFragment
    [..] // other fields
  }
}
${CustomerDetailsFragment}
[..] // other fragments
```

When I inspect the `activeCustomer` query, I see the `Customer_ID` so why do I get this error? Have I missed something? Thanks.